# Jupyter: grab JSON with multiple async calls and update cell

Tags: asynchronous, latex, jupyter

I am new to Jupyter and trying to put together a formatted HTML cell to present the content of a series of API calls. I know how to make API calls and I know how to present formatted HTML with `%%latex`. My question is **how can I generate the HTML only after all async calls return and using content from all those calls to create an HTML cell in a Jupyter notebook?**

Thanks for any suggestions.